# Formik onSubmit not registered within modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I trying to do formik within Modal itself, however, onSubmit button doesn't registered with. The alert function alert("test"); should appear. Do I need to input the onChange event inside the phone div?

```
.
.
<Modal
  show={this.state.testing}
  onHide={this.onHide}
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
  <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
   Hello World
  </Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>

<Formik    
onSubmit={({phone},{ setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
alert("test");
)

 render={({ errors, status, touched, isSubmitting }) => (
 <Form>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="phone">phone</label>
     <Field
     name="phone"
     type="text"
     className={
    "form-control" +
   (errors.phone&& touched.phone? " is-invalid" : "")
  }
 />
.
.
.
 <button
  type="submit"
  className="btn btn-primary"
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  >Update</button>
```

Alert("test")

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `Field` component, formik handles input with the onChange event automatically for you. So you don't need to change that.

Please consider these two notes:
`Form` component should be imported from formik like this:

```
import {  Form } from 'formik';
```

and your button should be inside it. something like this:

```
<Form>
  .
  .
  .
  <button
    type="submit"
    className="btn btn-primary"
    disabled={isSubmitting}
  >Update</button>
</Form>
```

if you still couldn't get the job done with these notes please share more of your code so i can help you. 
please let me know if you still have any problem